# Set default data encryption policy in exchange online

Tags: powershell, encryption, office365, exchange

I have recently enabled the customer key on my o365 tennant.

I have been able to set my mailboxes DEP with the following :

`Get-Mailbox | Set-Mailbox -DataEncryptionPolicy "MyDEPPolicyNmae"`

Now I'm trying to set the default DEP for new mailboxes.

I've looked in Set-MailboxPlan and in Set-MailboxCASPlan but i can't find any setting related to the DEP...

How do I define the default DEP on my Exchange online tennant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research, you couldn’t set default EDP for mailboxes via Set-MailboxPlan or Set-MailboxCASPlan.

If you want to set default EDP only for new mailboxes, I believe scripts will be a better way to do this. But I’m so sorry for that I’m not good at scripts, you could seek for a script expert who will give the most accurate advice.

Comment: I can do a scrpt without problem, but I wanted to try to find a way to do it without. An integrated way is almost always a better way :-)

Comment: How about combining scripts and task manager?

Answer (score -1):

Assign a DEP to a mailbox in Exchange Online

`Set-Mailbox -Identity <MailboxIdParameter> -DataEncryptionPolicy <PolicyName>`

Validate that the DEP Policy has been assigned to the mailbox.

`Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity <GeneralMailboxOrMailUserIdParameter> | format-list IsEncrypted`

The identity parameter can be the username, useralias and can be the the domainname\username format.

The proper output from the return on validating is "true"

Comment: Thanks but that's just to assign a DEP to an exiting mailbox, not to set it as the default for any futur new ones...